# Navigation in react native iOS

Tags: react-native, navigator

I have a Navigator component in my react native app.

It is supposed to navigate between different pages.

When I run the project, It is working fine in Simulator.

But, when I run the app in device (ipad), It is not going on second page.

XCode console throws an error saying  " Listeners not binded "

How to solve this issue ?

index.ios.js -

```js
/**
 * Sample React Native App
 * https://github.com/facebook/react-native
 * @flow
 */

import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {
  AppRegistry,
  Image,
  ListView,
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  Navigator,
  View
} from 'react-native';

var SplashPage = require('./js/SplashPage');
var MainPage = require('./js/MainPage');
var PersonPage = require('./js/PersonPage');
var VotePage = require('./js/VotePage');
var VoteDetailsPage = require('./js/VoteDetailsPage');
var PersonByLocationPage = require('./js/PersonByLocationPage');
var SearchRepresPage = require('./js/SearchRepresPage');
var navigator;


class Netizen extends Component {


   render() {

    return (
      <Navigator
          ref={(nav) => { navigator = nav; }}
          initialRoute={{id: 'SplashPage', name: 'Index'}}
          renderScene={this.renderScene.bind(this)}
          configureScene={(route) => {
            if (route.sceneConfig) {
              return route.sceneConfig;
            }
            return Navigator.SceneConfigs.FloatFromRight;
          }} />
    );
  }

  renderScene(route, navigator) {
    var routeId = route.id;

    if (routeId === 'SplashPage') {
      return (
        <SplashPage
          navigator={navigator} data={route.data}/>
      );
    }
    if (routeId === 'MainPage') {
      return (
        <MainPage
            navigator={navigator} data={route.data}/>
      );
    }
    if (routeId === 'PersonPage') {
      return (
        <PersonPage
          navigator={navigator} data={route.data}/>
      );
    }
    if (routeId === 'VotePage') {
      return (
        <VotePage
            navigator={navigator} data={route.data}/>
      );
    }
    if (routeId === 'VoteDetailsPage') {
      return (
        <VoteDetailsPage
            navigator={navigator} data={route.data}/>
      );
    }
    if (routeId === 'PersonByLocationPage') {
      return (
        <PersonByLocationPage
            navigator={navigator} data={route.data}/>
      );
    }
    if (routeId === 'SearchRepresPage') {
      return (
        <SearchRepresPage
            navigator={navigator} data={route.data}/>
      );
    }
    return this.noRoute(navigator);

  }

  noRoute(navigator) {
    return (
      <View style={{flex: 1, alignItems: 'stretch', justifyContent: 'center'}}>
        <TouchableOpacity style={{flex: 1, alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center'}}
            onPress={() => navigator.pop()}>
          <Text style={{color: 'red', fontWeight: 'bold'}}>请在 index.js 的 renderScene 中配置这个页面的路由</Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
      </View>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
    backgroundColor: '#F5FCFF',
  },
  welcome: {
    fontSize: 20,
    textAlign: 'center',
    margin: 10,
  },
  instructions: {
    textAlign: 'center',
    color: '#333333',
    marginBottom: 5,
  },
  shareText: {
    fontSize: 20,
    margin: 10,
  }
});

AppRegistry.registerComponent('Netizen', () => Netizen);
```

MainPage.js -

```js
render() {
    return (
      <Navigator
          renderScene={this.renderScene.bind(this)}
          navigator={this.props.navigator}
          navigationBar={
            <Navigator.NavigationBar style={{backgroundColor: '#246dd5'}}
                routeMapper={NavigationBarRouteMapper} />
          }
         />
    );
  }
```

Note - Navigation is working in Simulator, but not in iOS

Comment: could you please post some code?

Comment: I have added some code. Can you have a look please ?